# Using PHP's "for". Instead of sequential numbers, use specific numbers

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm pretty new to PHP and want to write a "for" statement based on IDs of a page. The problem is that the IDs are not sequential (by that I mean they are not increasing by 1 each time ie. 1,2,3,4,5). Is there a way to use "for" to use specific numbers? For example (pseudocode)

```
for IDnumbers i = (1,5,7,23,28,34)
 echo "function1(i)"
 echo "function2(i)"
end
```

I hope that makes sense. I basically want functions associated with each post ID to be returned, but I want the IDnumbers to be specific. Sorry if this is a basic question!

edit: wow, that really was basic. Thanks guys!

Comment: If an answer was helpful, please upvote it; and please accept an answer to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// create an array
$numbers = array(1,5,7,23,28,34);

// loop over it
foreach($numbers as $number){
    echo function1($number);
    echo function2($number);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (array(1,5,7,23,28,34) as $n) {
  echo "function1($n)";
  echo "function2($n)";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach( Array(1,5,7,23,28,34) as $i) {
    // do stuff with $i
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the numbers in an array and use a [`foreach`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$IDNumbers = array(1,5,7,23,28,34);
foreach($nums as $num)
{
   echo function1($num);
   echo function2($num);
}
```

Read more about [php foreach here.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
IDnumbers = array(1,5,7,23,28,34)
 foreach IDnumbers as id
 echo "function1(id)"
 echo "function2(id)"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you MUST use FOR, then you can do this:

```
$IDNumbers = (1,5,7,23,28,34);

for($i = 0; $i < count($IDNumbers); $i++):
    echo function1($IDNumbers[$i]);
endfor;
```

This is because even though you stored a number as the value in a numeric array, it still orders it sequentially in reference to the identifiers and where they were added. The value may be 7, but its pointer is 2 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in this case)